# What are all the statuses of policy center transactions

Tags: transactions, guidewire, gosu

Can someone explain the states of policy center transactions.
What is the meaning of each transaction state/status?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Your question is so general. Can you elaborate your question with some additional detail. It would be better for us to clarify it.

Comment: Hi Arun, I mean what is the meaning of each transaction state i.e. if the transactions is in draft state what it means? If the transaction is in quote state what it means? In the same way if the transaction is in bound state what it means? Like this how many states are there for a transaction in guidewire? What exactly the each state refers?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Policy Center GW studio,then the best way from my point of view is to refer description available for each typecode (each Status) in the typelist (PolicyPeriodStatus.ttx). Its very clear to understand when, how and what status used for each policy transaction when you go through each typecode in the typelist. Assuming that your GW studio has the OOTB PolicyPeriodStatus.ttx typecodes.